# How do I apply AllShortestPaths() on certain edges only between two defined vertices?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How do I apply AllShortestPaths() on certain edges only between two defined vertices?

Here is the query:

```
MATCH
    (from: SHIPPING_NODE {...}),
    (to: SHIPPING_NODE {...}), 
    paths = allShortestPaths((from)-[connection:CONNECT*]->(to))
WITH
    ....
RETURN delay_min, delay_max, price, route
```

When I add `WHERE connection.field_value > 10` to the query, I get the following:

```
Type mismatch: expected Map, Node or Relationship but was Collection<Relationship> (line 5, column 7 (offset: 267))
"WHERE connection.field_value > 10"
connection has some fields that I need to select specifically
```

Note: I can clear the error by removing the star (*) from `allShortestPaths((from)-[connection:CONNECT*]->(to))` but then nothing gets returned anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a path contains more than one relationship, you'll get a collection of relationships.

You can specify that ALL connection relationship should have a field value bigger than 10 :

```
WHERE ALL(x IN rels(paths) WHERE x.field_value > 10)
```

Reference : http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-predicates.html#functions-all